# How to capitalize Label.text?

Tags: vb.net

I have written a program that detects the pressed key and adds the key value to a label.

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    Label23.Text = Label23.Text & e.KeyChar
    If Label1.Text = Label23.Text Then
        PictureBox1.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is label1 is uppercase (and I can't make it in small letters) and label23 (to which the value is adding) is lowercase. Is there any way in which I can **make the value of label as uppercase** or make e.KeyChar to add capital letters to the label?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look at the [String.ToUpper()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupper%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function.

```
Label23.Text = Label23.Text.ToUpper();
```

There is also the [String.ToLower()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolower%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
Label23.Text = Label23.Text.ToLower();
```